# Does python have compare and swap operations

Tags: python, concurrency

Trying to find if the python support CAS operations, lock free programming, concurrency like in java?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python does not have those operations.  Java has more sophisticated concurrency controls than Python does.

CPython (the typical implementation almost everyone uses) has a Global Interpreter Lock that you will want to understand.

Jython is a Python implementation on the JVM, and so shares many of the concurrency characteristics of Java.