# Compare and swap instruction in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, c++11

Is it possible to have a CAS instruction in python? CAS = compare and swap.

I'm looking for something equivalent for expression in `C++`:

```
std::atomic<T> a;
a.compare_exchange_strong(x, y);
```

Comment: Python is the wrong language to be fiddling around with stuff like this. Try SSEs.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219326/does-python-have-compare-and-swap-operations.

Answer (score 4):

Python doesn't have [CAS operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219326/does-python-have-compare-and-swap-operations). As you know CAS is an atomic instruction used in multithreading to achieve synchronization. C++ has a much more sophisticated multithreading and synchronization than Python.

Comment: ok, but what can be considered as atomic operation in Python?

Comment: @Gilgamesz See ["What kinds of global value mutation are thread-safe?"](https://docs.python.org/3.6/faq/library.html#what-kinds-of-global-value-mutation-are-thread-safe) and ["Which Python Operations Are Atomic?"](http://blog.qqrs.us/blog/2016/05/01/which-python-operations-are-atomic/). In short: Many operations translate to a single bytecode instruction and are atomic because of Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)